# Kirchhoff's circuit laws

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

$ℰ_1,ℰ_2,R_1,R_2,R_3$ is known.
I have a practice problem which I can not solve. The question is the Voltage between dots A and B, I would also like to know the current passing trough all the places if the capacitor wasn't there.$ℰ_1,ℰ_2,R_1,R_2,R_3$ is known. In the solutions it says that $-ℰ_2=-I_3R_3+I_2R_2$ and that does not make sense to me. The current passing trough Resistor 3 is not $I_3$. Please help.

When I write $I_3$  means the third $I$, there is $I_1$,$ I_2$ and $I_3$, same with $-ℰ_2,R_3,I_2 and R_2$.

$R_1=50 \Omega$
$R_2=70 \Omega$
$R_3=130 \Omega$
$ℰ_1=6V$
$ℰ_2=2V$

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You didn't tell the time after which we have to find. Assuming that long enough time has passed I3 is actually the current passing through R3 since no flow of current to right of topmost node will happen so all the current will pass through R3 using nodal analysis

Answer (score 1):

> In the solutions it says that -$ℰ_2=-I_3R_3+I_2R_2$ and that does not make sense to me.

This is essentially *KVL* for the loop including $E_2, R_3$, and $R_2$.

> The current passing trough Resistor 3 is not $I_3$. 
>   Please help.

Use KCL at node "B". Since you're asking about the situation where "the capacitor wasn't there", no DC current flows through the capacitor's branch, and all the current through $E_2$ (named as $I_3$) must flow through $R_3$.